# What is the best way to call channel9 api for getting video?

Tags: msdn

Lets say that i have URL to channel9 movie;

Ex: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Office-365-Tips--Tricks/01-Wprowadzenie

And I want to display this movie on my site, and display some information for it ex. duration.

All what I know already is that, I can get list of movies by  calling

https://channel9.msdn.com/odata/Entries and skipping it +25 for showing next 25 results.

My implementation right now is something like:

1. Get first 25 elements from api
2. Iterate throught them
3. compare my url with elementFromApi[i].url 
   Its working but I don't like this solution, it is non elegant and slow as hell. I have no knowledge about the api so i dunno know how to refactor this^.

Maybe someone of You can help me.

PS. I need information from api, embed iframe with given url is not the solution here :)
PS2. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

I got this requirement through my client and I ended up doing it using RSS! In your use case the URL is https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Office-365-Tips--Tricks/01-Wprowadzenie - Simply we can read the rss by using the link https://s.ch9.ms/Series/Office-365-Tips--Tricks/rss/mp4 - In PowerShell we can explore the content with the below piece of code

```
$Sessions = Invoke-Restmethod -Uri 'https://s.ch9.ms/Series/Office-365-Tips--Tricks/rss/mp4' -UseDefaultCredentials
foreach($Session in $Sessions) {
    $Duration = [timespan]::FromSeconds($Session.duration)
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Title = $Session.title
        Duration = ("{0:0}:{1:00}:{2:00}" -f ($Duration.Hours , $Duration.Minutes , $Duration.Seconds))
        Creator = $Session.creator
        "URl(MP3)" = $Session.group.content.url[0]
        "URl(MP4)" = $Session.group.content.url[1]
        "URl(webm)" = $Session.group.content.url[2]
        "URl(MP4High)" = $Session.group.content.url[3]
    }
}
```

Note: Code needs to be improvised! 
The same can be achieved using C# - But I am not a certified developer - So , I used PowerShell to meet client requirement.